# Форма не успевает получить данные после ajax запроса и не отправляет все нужные данные

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).on('click','.locations',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(data.length > 1){
    $.post('/home/locations',{'locations': JSON.stringify(data)},function(result){
        res = JSON.parse(result);
        if(res['resp'] == 1){
            $('.map_id').val(res['map_id']);
        }
    });}
$('form').submit();});
```

Сам запрос. Пробовал сделать prevent (отключение submit) но данные приходят после сабмита и бд не получает значение с .map_id

Comment: на форме есть action = "javascript:void(null);" ?

Comment: Да, на форме есть action = "javascript:void(null);"

Comment: дак вы не хотите сабмит сделать в success-обработчике аякс запроса то? зы: зачем вам `stringify` ?

Comment: Я хочу провести сабмит, но только после того как в .map_Id занесется результат полученный с аякс запроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенесите submit в колбек

```js
$(document).on('click','.locations',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(data.length > 1){
    $.post('/home/locations',{'locations': JSON.stringify(data)},function(result){
        res = JSON.parse(result);
        if(res['resp'] == 1){
            $('.map_id').val(res['map_id']);
        }
        $('form').submit();})
    });}
```